# Controllability's dependence on B matrix

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

Assuming the LTI system:

$\dot{x}=Ax+Bu\\$ , where $x\in R^n$

I understand that

1. the $B$ matrix is usually given, and it is up to us to derive the optimal $u$ given an initial state of the system and a desired state where we want the system to arrive, in a finite time
2. a full-diagonal $B$ matrix could guarantee global controllability for the system
3. any $B$ matrix has to be dependent on the system and the application

In case the $B$ matrix is not *a priori* given, how could we cook up the "ideal" $B$ matrix, or at least any possible matrix that can render the system controllable? Let's consider that we have the freedom to choose the placement of actuators (see comments below)

potential ways, that might or might not be correct:

1. calculating the controllability matrix for any possible combination and keep those combinations that offer ideally global controllability, or at least the maximum rank of the controllability matrix. But this is computationally too demanding
2. through PBH test, finding the eigenvalues of $A$ matrix and accordingly deciding for the minimum and maximum number of columns of $B$ matrix. But this implies that we know or can find, the values of the components of the $B$ matrix

Comment: Normally for a given physical LTI system one would be able to derive a $B$, or are you considering the case where one might still have the freedom to choose the placement of actuators?

Comment: Exactly the second case. I am considering a system, where the placement of actuators can vary. 
Consider for example, a network whose nodes represent brain regions and the links therein, brain areas connections.

Comment: "Ideal" $B$ matrix can be many things depending on your purpose. Why not use a $B$ that allows you to assign a specific eigenstructure to the system? Or one that can be used to robustly stabilize the system against parameter uncertainties or external noise. Even one that can individually control each state or state group. I think it would be a very interesting problem if there were some constraints and goals.

Comment: the ideal one would be that with which we could render the system globally controllable with the minimum number of nodes, given the least energy used for the input. The placement of the actuators can vary as it was mentioned above, so, there are more than one possible choices. I am not sure of how to assign a specific eigenstructure just with the B matrix. I was aware that the placement of poles happens with the u(t) in whose optimal form, it contains the expression for the optimal B..

Answer (score 1):

The PBH test would to me seem the way to go. Namely this requires

$$
\text{rank}\!\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
B & A - \lambda\,I
\end{bmatrix}
\right) = n, \tag{1}
$$

or equivalently

$$
x^\top
\begin{bmatrix}
B & A - \lambda\,I
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
B & A - \lambda\,I
\end{bmatrix}^\top
x > 0, \ \forall\,x\neq0. \tag{2}
$$

Expanding this yields

$$
x^\top B\,B^\top x + x^\top (A - \lambda\,I)\,(A - \lambda\,I)^\top x > 0, \tag{3}
$$

where the quadratic term in $A$ is only zero for $\lambda$ any eigenvalue of $A$ and $x$ a linear combination of eigenvectors corresponding to that eigenvalue (however often eigenvalues are simple so there would be only one corresponding eigenvector). The pair $(A,B)$ is therefore controllable if $B^\top v\neq 0$ for $v$ all vectors in the span of eigenvectors corresponding to each eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ of $A^\top$. In other words $B^\top V_i$ needs to be full rank, where the columns of $V_i$ are the eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda_i$.

---

For example when

$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix},
$$

yields

\begin{align}
\lambda_1&=1, \quad V_1 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}, \\
\lambda_2&=2, \quad V_2 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1
\end{bmatrix},
\end{align}

so from $V_1$ it follows that $B$ should have at least two columns. If instead the matrix is changed slightly to

$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix},
$$

yields

\begin{align}
\lambda_1&=1, \quad V_1 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}, \\
\lambda_2&=2, \quad V_2 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1
\end{bmatrix},
\end{align}

so a single column for $B$ should be enough in this case. So it can be noted that repeated eigenvalues do not always require a higher number of columns of $B$.